# PostJsonAsync how to handle http responses

Tags: blazor

How will i handle different HTTP responses with (it works but cant handle responses)

```
await Http.PostJsonAsync($"{ServiceExtensions.BaseWebApiUrl}api/authenticate/newpassword", credentials);
```

i tried (gives http // 400 - bad request)

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.PostAsync($"{ServiceExtensions.BaseWebApiUrl}api/authenticate/newpassword", new StringContent(credentials.Email,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

but this gives me a bad request as its not forming the request the same way apparently.

my credentials contains just a simple email address so far, but i would like to be able to handle different HTTP responses from the WEB API,

WEB API

```
[HttpPost("NewPassword")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> NewPassword(NewPasswordObject newPasswordObject)
        {
        ...//
        }
```

the second one does not even hit this function, even if i try with [FromBody]

Comment: What is the type of your app ? Blazor WebAssembly App or Blazor Server App ?

Comment: @enet running serverside right now, should it change something here?

Comment: Yes, HttpClient in WebAssembly Blazor App is not the actual HttpClient object. It is based on the JavaScript Fetch Api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
...
var serializedValue = JsonSerializer.Serialize(credentials)
using var stringContent = new StringContent(serializedValue,
    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var url = $"{ServiceExtensions.BaseWebApiUrl}api/authenticate/newpassword";
using var response = await Http.PostAsync(url, stringContent)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: appreciate your help, but this way it does not hit my API function either.. i just can't seems to figure out how it form the request different :/

Comment: you forgot to serialize your value.

Comment: This one works, if i did credentials instead of credentials.Email !